# How to add labels inside circles of the Venn diagram in python?

Tags: python, venn-diagram, matplotlib-venn

I am using the matplotlib_venn.venn2 function to plot the Venn diagram in a single figure.
My code:

```
from matplotlib_venn import venn2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
total = 150
# depict venn diagram
venn2(subsets = (61, 48, 13), set_labels = ('Advanced Mathematics', 'linear Algebra'),
      set_colors=('#00909e', '#f67280'),
    subset_label_formatter=lambda x: f"{(x/total):1.0%}"
)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

However, I wanted to add the topics of each subject inside the circle, for example inside Advanced Mathematics the following topics should be written (Calculus and analysis, Logic, Number theory) and Linear Algebra topics (Mathematical operations, Matrix inverses and determinants) should be written inside Linear Algebra.

Comment: I don't think it's too hard to apply the suggestions already given in answers to your actual needs.

Answer (score 2):

The `venn2` function used for creating two-circle Venn diagrams returns an object of type `VennDiagram`. This object provides access to the labels via the `get_label_by_id()` function. The IDs for two-circle diagrams are `'10'` (left), `'01'` (right), and `'11'` (intersection) according to the [source code of class `VennDiagram`](https://github.com/konstantint/matplotlib-venn/blob/master/matplotlib_venn/_common.py#L12). <sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLXd4.png)</sup>

So by assigning the result of the `venn2` call to a variable `diagram` will help adjust the subset labels:

```
subsets = (61, 48, 13)  # `subsets` is used in the next code box
diagram = venn2(
    subsets = subsets, 
    set_labels = ('Advanced Mathematics', 'linear Algebra'),
    set_colors=('#00909e', '#f67280')
)

# display the label IDs themselves as subgroup labels
for id in ('10','11','01'):
    diagram.get_label_by_id(id).set_text(id)

plt.show()
```

As discussed, there is no limitation to labels except the logic of formatting labels that comes with [matplotlib.text](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html?highlight=text#module-matplotlib.text). In other words, it's almost impossible to get the layout you described in the updated question. Here is what I tried to get as close as possible [replace the `for` loop with it]:

```
diagram.get_label_by_id('10').set_text(f"""
Calculus and analysis

Logic

{subsets[0]/total:1.0%}


Number theory

""")
diagram.get_label_by_id('01').set_text(f"""
Mathematical
operations

{subsets[1]/total:1.0%}

Matrix inverses
and determinants
""")
diagram.get_label_by_id('11').set_text(f'{subsets[2]/total:1.0%}')
```

But what I got from it …

[image]

… is not quite impressive. To do this, you really have to count rows (and don't forget the blank rows) to align the percentages vertically. From an aesthetic point of view, I would say that we are not using the right tool.

---

<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLXd4.png)</sup> As shown in the answer Nikolay Tsvetanov, the first IDs for three-circle Venn diagrams (`'100'`, `'010'`, `'110'`) work either.

Comment: @AlexAM Is it really about stuffing text into circles???

Answer (score 1):

you can set custom text to labels

```
labels = ['100', '010']
custom_text = ["Advanced Mathematics",'linear Algebra' ]
for label_id, text in zip(labels, custom_text):
    v.get_label_by_id(label_id).set_text(text)
```

Comment: what about texts ?  Calculus and analysis, Logic, Number theory for Advanced Mathematics and for Linear Algebra the following topics Mathematical operations, Matrix inverses and determinants

Comment: just change 
`custom_text =  ['Calculus and analysis\n, Logic\n, Number theory\n',  'Mathematical operations\n, Matrix inverses\n Determinants\n' ]` 
can be any string

Comment: @AlexAM It's not clear what you are asking here.

Comment: @ Wolf, i asking simply to add some text to circles, both way are not working

Comment: You have full control of the argument in the `set_text` call, there is no need to call it in a for loop, this is only for demonstration purposes. Try for example `v.get_label_by_id('10').set_text('whatever')` to set the text for the left circle.

Comment: probably you should assign  `v = venn2(subsets = (61, 48, 13), set_labels = ('Advanced Mathematics', 'linear Algebra'),
      set_colors=('#00909e', '#f67280'),
    subset_label_formatter=lambda x: f"{(x/total):1.0%}"
)`

Comment: @Nikolay Tsvetanov and Wolf, thank you, please check my expected output

Comment: you can recreate it with `get_label_by_id('10').set_text('whatever')` and some formating